# Can jacoco report aggregate be created using mvn surefire:test command?

Tags: maven, jacoco

This is my pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.10</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>prepare-unit-tests</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <destFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>report-aggregate</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>merge-results</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>merge</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <fileSets>
                    <fileSet>
                        <directory>${code.coverage.project.folder}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/jacoco.exec</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileSet>
                </fileSets>
                <destFile>${code.coverage.overall.data.folder}/aggregate.exec</destFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Report is generated successfully when I use the command mvn clean test but it is generated with zero percentage when I use mvn initialize surefire:test. Does the report generation not work successfully with mvn surefire:test?

Comment: If you call `surefire:test` you are calligng the goal of surefire directly without starting the lifecyle which means neither the life cycle phase `test`or others are executed... only the clean life cycle has been start which is not the default life cycle. BTW:Why are you configuring so many things?

Answer (score 0):

The whole configuration for using jacoco-maven-plugin is the following which results in a single aggregated report for unit- and integration tests within a single module build:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
          <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>merge</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>merge</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <configuration>
          <fileSets>
            <fileSet>
              <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>*.exec</include>
              </includes>
            </fileSet>
          </fileSets>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Usually you should define once the version of the jacoco-maven-plugin which is done by default within `pluginManagement` like this:

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.8.10</version>
        </plugin>
        ..
      ..
    ..
  </build>
```

This can simply being called via `mvn verify`... that's it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I want the report aggregate to get generated using mvn surefire:test. Is it not possible? I tried it with mvn clean verify and mvn clean test and they worked. I want it to work with mvn surefire:test. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why would you like to use the goal instead of the life cycle?

Comment: We are calling individual goals because this is part of a very large (multi-hour) build and different parts of our pipeline handle different things. The build system is actually handling the orchestration the of maven goals.

Comment: Orchestration is the job of Maven itself... This example is for a single module setup... Maven *is* the build system.... If you have a multi hour build ... why? So many modules? Tests ? Which Maven version, plugins are up-to-date? Using parallelization?